# Why g++ cannot compile nested friend class usage while clang++ can?

Tags: c++, c++14, inner-classes

As far as I know, `friend class Foo` in a class `Bar` can make `Foo` have access to all members in `Bar`. I wrote the code below, it passes compilation with `clang++ main.cc -std=c++14`, also `c++11`. However `g++` cannot in both versions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo) {
        return os << foo.bar.data;
    }

   public:
    Foo() = default;

    class Bar {
        friend class Foo;
        Bar(int _data = 0) : data(_data) {}

       private:
        int data;
    };

   private:
    Bar bar;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At first I thought it may be that operator is special, so I wrote a test function `friend void test(const Foo &foo) { std::cout << foo.bar.data << std::endl; }` rather than `std::ostream & operator`. The result is the same as above.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    friend void test(const Foo& foo) {
        std::cout << foo.bar.data << std::endl;
    }

   public:
    Foo() = default;

    class Bar {
        friend class Foo;
        Bar(int _data = 0) : data(_data) {}

       private:
        int data;
    };

   private:
    Bar bar;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    test(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

`g++` result before substitution:

```sh
main.cc: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo&)’:
main.cc:5:30: error: ‘int Foo::Bar::data’ is private within this context
    5 |         return os << foo.bar.data;
      |                              ^~~~
main.cc:16:13: note: declared private here
   16 |         int data;
      |             ^~~~
```

after:

```sh
main.cc: In function ‘void test(const Foo&)’:
main.cc:5:30: error: ‘int Foo::Bar::data’ is private within this context
    5 |         std::cout << foo.bar.data << std::endl;
      |                              ^~~~
main.cc:16:13: note: declared private here
   16 |         int data;
      |             ^~~~
```

I wonder if this is a special occasion that `g++` didn't implement while `clang++` did, or things are special when it's in a nested class.

Comment: I'm afraid G++ is actually correct

Comment: It's a bug in clang https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31747

Comment: @n.'p the linked bug has `B`'s methods accessing `A`'s private data.  The above question has `A`'s methods accessing `B`'s private data with `friend` permission.  On its face, not the same.

Comment: SHP, did you try moving the function body out of the class?  Predeclaring `A`?  Predeclaring operator?  Friending operator directly? Sometimes in-class-body definitions have quirky rules.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont In both cases there is private data of class X which is accessed by a *friend* of class Y, where class Y has access to private parts of X for any reason. What is nested where is actually irrelevant.

Comment: So, Foo is a friend of Bar, operator<< is a friend of Foo, but operator<< is not a friend of Bar. Not quite the same bug as linked, as operator<< isn't an enclosed class accessing private parts of Foo.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, I've tried, in this version both compilers gave the same compilation error. see link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N7j3p7kz33/

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the direction, I've found the reason of error: according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend, friend is not transitive. `ostream& operator<<` is a friend of `Foo`, `Foo` is a friend of `Bar`, which breaks the constraint. So this is a bug of clang?.